# 7zip archive extraction fails

Tags: archive, 7z

I'm going to use `bigfile`, `smallfile1`, and `smallfile2` to always refer to the same file names without file extension. The two small ones don't have any.

I created an encrypted 7zip archive using this command:

```
7z a -mx=0 -p bigfile.7z smallfile1 smallfile2 bigfile.tar
```

Now, when I try to extract the archive, this happens:

```
$ 7z e bigfile.7z 

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)

Processing archive: bigfile.7z


Enter password (will not be echoed) :
Extracting  smallfile1
Extracting  smallfile2
Extracting  bigfile.tar     Data Error in encrypted file. Wrong password?

Sub items Errors: 1
```

`smallfile1` and `smallfile2` are extracted correctly. I can verify this because I know that `smallfile1` is a text file containing the code I used to create `bigfile.tar` and `smallfile2` contains the sha256sum of `bigfile.tar`. 43 783 352 320 Byte (43.8 GB) of `bigfile.tar` are written to the disk before the above-mentioned error message is printed and `7z` terminates. I don't remember the exact size of `bigfile.tar` but I do remember that `bigfile.7z`'s size was approximately its size and it's 75 467 408 086 Byte (75.5 GB) in size. I computed `bigfile.7z`'s sha256sum right after creating it and stored it. The instance of `bigfile.7z` I have now still produces this hash sum.

How do I get `bigfile.tar` back?

Comment: @Kiwy That's not the case. I answered my own question by now.

Comment: Thus far, 4 people have voted to close this question as off-topic because they feel like no answer can be found because others can't reproduce the problem. However, this is a good example of why this reason for closing questions for that reason is stupid. Someone who already experienced that problem could've come across this question and pointed out that that error message is produced incorrectly when you run out of storage space.

Comment: Still if we add all the information we could have reproduce the error. if we did try the same stuff as you,  issue wasn't reproductible. I'm glad you find the issue though.

Answer (score 2):

Despite of the error message reading "Data Error in encrypted file. Wrong password?", the problem was that I ran out of storage space on the medium I was extracting the archive on.